# Accessing properties of a prop object that is asynchronously defined

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous

My child component receives a prop called `config`, which is an object whose properties I display in my template or pass as props to other components:

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <h2 class="title">
      {{ config.section_header }}
    </h2>

    <custom-button
      v-for="(button, i) in config.section_buttons"
      :key="i"
      v-bind="button"
    />
  </section>
</template>
```

The parent view component itself gets the `config` object from the store.

In my parent view component:

```
created () {
  this.initializeStore()
},
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    config: state => state.template?.section ?? null
  })
}
```

The store is populated asynchronously via an `Axios` call:

```
export const actions = {
  initializeStore ({ state, commit }, data) {
    this.$axios.get('/path/to/api/endpoint')
      .then((res) => {
        // state object gets populated
      })
  }
}
```

Because the `config` prop is defined only after the store API call resolves, my component throws `undefined` error everywhere I'm trying to display parts of it. For example:

> Cannot read property 'section_buttons' of null

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using promises or async/await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In initial rendering your data has not been available yet, so you've to add a conditional rendering everywhere you get that error :

```html
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <h2 class="title" v-if="config">
      {{ config.section_header }}
    </h2>
    <template v-if="config && config.section_buttons">
      <custom-button
        v-for="(button, i) in config.section_buttons"
        :key="i"
        v-bind="button"
      />
    </template> 
 </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! Still getting the same error though: `Cannot read property 'section_buttons' of null`. Also getting similar error for `{{ config.section_header }}`

Comment: yes you should do `<template v-if="config && config.section_buttons">`  please check the edited answer